# On calculating temperature differences between zipcodes

Tags: search, brute-force, temperature

Prop A. I wrote a zipcode server that gives me 32,000 zip codes of USA.
Each zipcode has an associated lat-long.
Given 2 zipcodes, I can find the distance between them using their lat-longs.

Prop B. I also wrote a weather server where you can input atmost 200 zipcodes and it spits out the temperature at each of those zipcodes.

Person tells me his zipcode is Z, temperature is T.
He asks me, what's the nearest place from Z where its atleast 10 degrees cooler ?

So I get a list of 200 zipcodes from Z sorted by distance ( using Prop A).
I feed that to B and get 200 temperatures.
If none are 10 degrees cooler, I get the next 200 zipcodes and repeat until done.

Problem: This seems quite inefficient and brute-force. I feel there's some Physics insight I'm missing. Its not always true that if you go north the temperatures cool down & going south they heat up. So direction doesn't help. Altitude probably does ( mountains cooler than valleys ) but zipcodes data keyed to altitude is hard to find.

Can you guys think of some smarter way to go about this ? Any suggestions appreciated. 
Note: The weather data is expensive. You can hit the weather server a few times only, and you can only get 200 temperatures at each time. ( otoh, the distances between any 2 zipcodes are precomputed constants, and there is no cost to get that. )

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by binary sorting all of the zip codes and grabbing all of them lower than the user's zip code in the sorted list, then doing the same on that subset for distance. This should be reasonably fast - binary sort is  log(n), so you won't kill yourself on the sorts.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment from the physics forum that this is not a physics problem, but some insights from physics (or mathematics at least) might indeed be in order.  If you are able to cheaply obtain the weather data, you might be able to set up a dataset and perform analysis once to guide your search.

Specifically, record the temperature for each location concurrently.  Then, for each location, calculate the change in temperature to each contiguous zip code and associate that with a relative coordinate (i.e. the direction to the neighboring zip) and store this list ordered by temperature.  When someone enters a query zip, your algorithm would start with the zip at the top of the list and work it's way down.  Each non-satisfactory answer is added to a stack.  If none of the neighboring zips meets the criteria (in this case 10 degrees cooler), the algorithm would start working through the new stack repeating the algorithm.

I am not a wonderful programmer so I won't give any code, but it seems to me that this would "follow" the natural contours of the temperature map better than a brute force search and would retain primacy on the proximity of the result.  If you set up your initial dataset with several concurrent temperature measurements, you could time average those for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is best for stackoverflow.

Combine the databases.

Write a query abs(lat-lat_o) + abs(long-long_0) < 2.00 AND temp < temp_0 - 10. That query will take advantage of indexing on your server.

If no results, increase 2.00 by a multiple and repeat.

If results, find which is closest. If the closest one is farther than the nearest edge of your bounding box, save that entry and increase 2.000 to that distance and see if one of those is closer.

Scales, uses database efficiently.